# Multiselect listbox bound to database in Delphi 6

Tags: delphi, data-binding, listbox

I'm using Delphi 6, and I want a database bound list box with multiselect.  I found three types of List boxes: `TListBox`, `TDBListBox` and `TDBLookupListBox`.

As far as I can understand, `TListbox` is not bound to database. `TDBListBox` and `TDBLookupListBox` can't be multiselected.

Is there a way to get a multiselect listbox binded to database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with databinding components is that they rely on a datasource and a datasource has only a single cursor. That is probably the reason why.

By the way, do you need to change the data? Else you could fill a normal listbox from a dataset. Or even use an invisible data listbox and copy the contents to a normal listbox.

Answer (score 3):

Not as far as I know.
The standard is that you offer with the list a bunch of values in which 1 represents the current record.
Unless you have a multivalued field (against best practices) I can't see how you could multiselect...

Or what you might want is actually a sub-table?

Comment: I want to create a filter for a table, and the listbox is one of the filter criteria.  I want to fill the listbox with a table from the database.

Answer (score 1):

DevExpress TcxDBListBox supports multiselect.  I use their multiselect drop down check box bound to a database, it's sweet.

The components have methods you can implement to convert to and from your list; EditValueToStates and StatesToEditValue. While the data I store is not normalized (I store a semi-colon delimited list of version numbers), I created a full text search index on the field, with a semi-colon as a delimiter, and now I can still perform optimized searches on that field.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own custom listbox component that descends from TCustomListBox and add a Datasource property for your list, and another property such as TStrings to be used as a container to hold selected values.  You could then post changes to your database using a button click.

Answer (score 1):

If you fiddle with some of the options of a TDBGrid and restrict the columns it displays, you can make something that looks a whole lot like a listbox.  Try setting the Options property to [dgTitles,dgTabs,dgRowSelect,dgAlwaysShowSelection,dgCancelOnExit,dgMultiSelect] and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

In a TDbLookupListBox you have the option to bind two different things to data; first you can bind the list to a dataset (ListSource/ListField/KeyField), second you can bind the selected item to a field in another dataset (DataSource, DataField). There is nothing conceptually wrong with wanting to bind the list of items to a dataset, and then manually manage multiple selections, however I don't think it is possible with the current implementation without subclassing and enabling the required control styles.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to François, I would use a normal TListbox and write code to insert all distinct values into the list, and then handle the multi-select values yourself.  Jeremy's solution also works, and the [DevExpress Express Quantum Grid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid/) has a nice filter system which might even save you some other programming.